# Not Generating Random Characters on Each Call

Tags: java, random

I'm hoping someone can point me in the direction of figuring out why my code does not create a random string of alphabetic characters each time it is called in the main class.

Here is my password randomizer class:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class PasswordRandomizer {
    private Random random = new Random();
    private int length;
    private int num;
    private String password = "";
    private String alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    private char character;

    public PasswordRandomizer(int length) {
        // Initialize the variable
        this.length = length;
    }

    public String createPassword() {
        while ( length > 0 ) {           
            num = this.random.nextInt(26);
            character = alphabet.charAt(num);
            password += character;
            length--;
        }
        return password;
    }
}
```

And for each call it only produces the exact same password. For example:

```
    public class Program {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PasswordRandomizer password = new PasswordRandomizer(13);
        System.out.println("Password: " + password.createPassword());
        System.out.println("Password: " + password.createPassword());
        System.out.println("Password: " + password.createPassword());
        System.out.println("Password: " + password.createPassword());
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to add a seed (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#setSeed(long))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After calling the `createPassword()` method the first time, `length` is 0. The further calls do nothing and return the previously generated `password`.

Make `password` a local variable in the `createPassword()` method and use a local variable to countdown length.

You should generally declare variables as local as possible. Only declare them at object level, if you want to share the value between different calls to methods of the object.

```
public class PasswordRandomizer {
    private Random random = new Random();
    private int length;
    private String alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

    public PasswordRandomizer(int length) {
        // Initialize the variable
        this.length = length;
    }

    public String createPassword() {
        int localLength = this.length;
        String password = "";
        while ( localLength > 0 ) {           
            int num = this.random.nextInt(26);
            char character = alphabet.charAt(num);
            password += character;
            localLength--;
        }
        return password;
    }
}
```

Comment: Also, `alphabet` is a constant, so should be `private static final String ALPHABET`. Of course, simply doing `char character = (char)('a' + num);` would be better still.

Comment: Thank you NineBarry & Andreas (I read your answer below as well). It makes total sense now that it's been explained. I will also keep in mind regarding ASCII/Unicode because I can see where it would make it much easier.

Answer (score 1):

You need to reset the `password` field and initialize the `length` variable so that `createPassword()` generates a new password on subsequent calls.  For example:

```
public String createPassword() {
    password = ""; // Reset the password.
    int length = this.length; // Initialize the password length.
    while (length > 0) {
        num = this.random.nextInt(26);
        character = alphabet.charAt(num);
        password += character;
        length--;
    }
    return password;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are initialising 'PasswordRandomizer password = new PasswordRandomizer(13);' once. So length = 13, length is instance variable, it reaches to 0, after calling createPassword method, so it is returning same password in later calls of createPassword function. Update Program.java like below.

```
public class Program {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PasswordRandomizer password = new PasswordRandomizer(13);
        System.out.println("Password: " + password.createPassword());

        password = new PasswordRandomizer(13);
        System.out.println("Password: " + password.createPassword());

        password = new PasswordRandomizer(13);
        System.out.println("Password: " + password.createPassword());

        password = new PasswordRandomizer(13);
        System.out.println("Password: " + password.createPassword());
    }
}
```

Or update your createPassword() like below.

```
 public String createPassword() {
        int length1 = length;
        password ="";
        while ( length1 > 0 ) {           
            num = random.nextInt(26);
            character = alphabet.charAt(num);
            password += character;
            length1--;
        }

        return password;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your fields have retained the value from the previous call to `createPassword()`, so nothing happens on subsequent calls.

The main issue is that `length` is `0` after the first call, and you didn't save the original value anywhere, so you have no idea what it should be.

---

Anyway, don't create *fields* for things that should be local *variables*.

Only `random` and `length` needs to be fields, and they should never be changed, so make them `final`.

Also, to convert a number `0-25` to a letter `a-z`, you can rely on the fact that those letters are consecutive in ASCII/Unicode, and simply write `'a' + num`, instead of doing a string lookup.

Since you know the length of the string to create, it's much faster to create a `char[]`, fill the characters and then create a `String` from it.

```
public class PasswordRandomizer {
    private final Random random = new Random();
    private final int length;

    public PasswordRandomizer(int length) {
        this.length = length;
    }

    public String createPassword() {
        char[] password = new char[this.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < this.length; i++)
            password[i] = (char)('a' + this.random.nextInt(26));
        return new String(password);
    }
}
```